Rendered more hooks than during the previous render. about hide or show menu items

import navigationConfig from "configs/NavigationConfig";

import useAuth from "hooks/useAuth";
import useUserType from "hooks/useType";

const { SubMenu } = Menu;
const { useBreakpoint } = Grid;



const setLocale = (isLocaleOn, localeKey) =>
  isLocaleOn ? <IntlMessage id={localeKey} /> : localeKey.toString();

const setDefaultOpen = (key) => {
  let keyList = [];
  let keyString = "";
  if (key) {
    const arr = key.split("-");
    for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
      const elm = arr[index];
      index === 0 ? (keyString = elm) : (keyString = `${keyString}-${elm}`);
      keyList.push(keyString);
    }
  }
  return keyList;
};

const useConstructor = (callBack = () => { }) => {
  const [hasBeenCalled, setHasBeenCalled] = useState(false);
  const data = callBack();
  if (hasBeenCalled) return data;
  setHasBeenCalled(true);
  return data;
};

const SideNavContent = (props) => {
  const {
    sideNavTheme,
    routeInfo,
    hideGroupTitle,
    localization,
    onMobileNavToggle,
  } = props;
  

  const data = useConstructor(() => {

    return navigationConfig;

  });

  const IsAuth = (premission) => {
    const { isAuth: isAuthenticated } = useAuth([premission]);
    return isAuthenticated;
  };

  const ExactAuth = (premission) => {
    const { exact } = useAuth([premission]);
    return exact;
  };

  const IsType = (requiredType) => {
    const { hasRequiredType } = useUserType([requiredType]);
    return hasRequiredType;
  };

  const isMobile = !utils.getBreakPoint(useBreakpoint()).includes("lg");
  const closeMobileNav = () => {
    if (isMobile) {
      onMobileNavToggle(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Menu
      theme={sideNavTheme === SIDE_NAV_LIGHT ? "light" : "dark"}
      mode="inline"
      style={{ height: "100%", borderRight: 0 }}
      defaultSelectedKeys={[routeInfo?.key]}
      defaultOpenKeys={setDefaultOpen(routeInfo?.key)}
      className={hideGroupTitle ? "hide-group-title" : ""}
    >
      {data.map((menu) =>
        menu.submenu.length > 0 ? (
          menu.exactAuth !== true ? (
            IsAuth(menu.premission) ? (
              (menu.userType === undefined || IsType(menu.userType)) ? (
                <Menu.ItemGroup
                  key={menu.key}
                  title={setLocale(localization, menu.title)}
                >
                  {menu.submenu.map((subMenuFirst) =>
                    subMenuFirst.submenu.length > 0 ? (
                      IsAuth(subMenuFirst.premission) ? (
                        <SubMenu
                          icon={
                            subMenuFirst.icon ? (
                              <Icon type={subMenuFirst?.icon} />
                            ) : null
                          }
                          key={subMenuFirst.key}
                          title={setLocale(localization, subMenuFirst.title)}
                        >
                          {subMenuFirst.submenu.map((subMenuSecond) =>
                            IsAuth(subMenuSecond.premission) ? (
                              <Menu.Item key={subMenuSecond.key}>
                                {subMenuSecond.icon ? (
                                  <Icon type={subMenuSecond?.icon} />
                                ) : null}
                                <span>
                                  {setLocale(localization, subMenuSecond.title)}
                                </span>
                                <Link
                                  onClick={() => closeMobileNav()}
                                  to={subMenuSecond.path}
                                />
                              </Menu.Item>
                            ) : null
                          )}
                        </SubMenu>
                      ) : null
                    ) : IsAuth(subMenuFirst.premission) ? (
                      (subMenuFirst.userType === undefined || IsType(subMenuFirst.userType)) ? (
                        <Menu.Item key={subMenuFirst.key}>
                          {subMenuFirst.icon ? (
                            <Icon type={subMenuFirst.icon} />
                          ) : null}
                          <span>{setLocale(localization, subMenuFirst.title)}</span>
                          <Link
                            onClick={() => closeMobileNav()}
                            to={subMenuFirst.path}
                          />
                        </Menu.Item>
                      ) : null
                    ) : null
                  )}
                </Menu.ItemGroup>
              ) : null
            ) : null
          ) : ExactAuth(menu.premission) ? (
            <Menu.ItemGroup
              key={menu.key}
              title={setLocale(localization, menu.title)}
            >
              {menu.submenu.map((subMenuFirst) =>
                subMenuFirst.submenu.length > 0 ? (
                  IsAuth(subMenuFirst.premission) ? (
                    <SubMenu
                      icon={
                        subMenuFirst.icon ? (
                          <Icon type={subMenuFirst?.icon} />
                        ) : null
                      }
                      key={subMenuFirst.key}
                      title={setLocale(localization, subMenuFirst.title)}
                    >
                      {subMenuFirst.submenu.map((subMenuSecond) =>
                        IsAuth(subMenuSecond.premission) ? (
                          <Menu.Item key={subMenuSecond.key}>
                            {subMenuSecond.icon ? (
                              <Icon type={subMenuSecond?.icon} />
                            ) : null}
                            <span>
                              {setLocale(localization, subMenuSecond.title)}
                            </span>
                            <Link
                              onClick={() => closeMobileNav()}
                              to={subMenuSecond.path}
                            />
                          </Menu.Item>
                        ) : null
                      )}
                    </SubMenu>
                  ) : null
                ) : IsAuth(subMenuFirst.premission) ? (
                  <Menu.Item key={subMenuFirst.key}>
                    {subMenuFirst.icon ? (
                      <Icon type={subMenuFirst.icon} />
                    ) : null}
                    <span>{setLocale(localization, subMenuFirst.title)}</span>
                    <Link
                      onClick={() => closeMobileNav()}
                      to={subMenuFirst.path}
                    />
                  </Menu.Item>
                ) : null
              )}
            </Menu.ItemGroup>
          ) : null
        ) : IsAuth(menu.premission) ? (
          <Menu.Item key={menu.key}>
            {menu.icon ? <Icon type={menu?.icon} /> : null}
            <span>{setLocale(localization, menu?.title)}</span>
            {menu.path ? (
              <Link onClick={() => closeMobileNav()} to={menu.path} />
            ) : null}
          </Menu.Item>
        ) : null
      )}
    </Menu>
  );
};


const MenuContent = (props) => {
  return props.type === NAV_TYPE_SIDE ? (
    <SideNavContent {...props} />
  ) : (
    <TopNavContent {...props} />
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ theme }) => {
  const { sideNavTheme, topNavColor } = theme;
  return { sideNavTheme, topNavColor };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { onMobileNavToggle })(MenuContent);


this is my menuContent component .
import {
  DashboardOutlined,
  UserOutlined,
  TeamOutlined,
  VideoCameraOutlined,
  CalendarOutlined,
  SettingOutlined,
  DollarOutlined,
  FileTextOutlined,
  PlusOutlined,
  BankOutlined
} from '@ant-design/icons';
import { APP_PREFIX_PATH } from 'configs/AppConfig'
import useUserType from "hooks/useType";

const IsType = (requiredType) => {
  const { hasRequiredType } = useUserType([requiredType]);
  return hasRequiredType;
};

const NewSideBar = [
  {
    key: 'dashboard',
    path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/dashboard`,
    title: 'sidenav.dashboard',
    icon: DashboardOutlined,
    breadcrumb: false,
    submenu: [
      {
        key: 'dashboard',
        path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/dashboard`,
        title: 'sidenav.dashboard',
        icon: DashboardOutlined,
        premission:['ROLE_CLIENT'],
        breadcrumb: false,
        submenu: []
      },
      {
        key: 'dashboard',
        path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/admin/home`,
        title: 'sidenav.dashboard',
        icon: DashboardOutlined,
        breadcrumb: false,
        premission:['ROLE_ADMIN'],
        submenu: []
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    key: 'meetings',
    path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/meetings`,
    title: 'meetings',
    icon: DashboardOutlined,
    breadcrumb: false,
    premission:['ROLE_CLIENT'],
    submenu: [
      {
        key: 'meetings',
        path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/meetings/all`,
        title: 'meetings',
        icon: VideoCameraOutlined,
        breadcrumb: false,
        submenu: []
      },
      {
        key: 'calendar',
        path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/meetings/calendar`,
        title: 'calendar',
        icon: CalendarOutlined,
        breadcrumb: false,
        submenu: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    key: 'users',
    path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/users`,
    title: 'Members',
    icon: TeamOutlined,
    breadcrumb: false,
    premission:['ROLE_CLIENT'],
    submenu: [
      {
        key: 'users',
        path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/users/member`,
        title: 'members',
        icon: UserOutlined,
        submenu: [],
        breadcrumb: false,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    key: 'teams',
    path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/team`,
    title: 'Teams',
    icon: TeamOutlined,
    breadcrumb: false,
    premission:['ROLE_CLIENT'],
    userType:"owner",
    submenu: [
      {
        key: 'add_team',
        path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/team/add`,
        title: 'Add team',
        icon: PlusOutlined,
        breadcrumb: false,
        submenu: [],
      },
      {
        key: 'team_list',
        path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/team/list`,
        title: 'Team list',
        icon: TeamOutlined,
        breadcrumb: false,
        submenu: []
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    key: 'users',
    path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/users`,
    title: 'Users',
    breadcrumb: false,
    premission:['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    submenu: [
      {
        key: 'add_user',
        path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/admin/users/add`,
        title: 'Add user',
        icon: PlusOutlined,
        submenu: [],
        breadcrumb: false,
      },
      {
        key: 'users',
        path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/admin/users/list`,
        title: 'User list',
        icon: TeamOutlined,
        submenu: [],
        breadcrumb: false,
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    key: 'organisation',
    path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/organisations`,
    title: 'Users',
    breadcrumb: false,
    premission:['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    submenu: [
      {
        key: 'add_organisation',
        path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/admin/organisations/add`,
        title: 'Add organisation',
        icon: PlusOutlined,
        submenu: [],
        breadcrumb: false,
      },
      {
        key: 'organisations',
        path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/admin/organisations/list`,
        title: 'Organisation list',
        icon: BankOutlined,
        submenu: [],
        breadcrumb: false,
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    key: 'settings',
    path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}`,
    title: 'settings',
    icon: TeamOutlined,
    breadcrumb: false,
    premission:['ROLE_CLIENT'],
    submenu: [
      {
        key: 'settings',
        path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/setting`,
        title: 'settings',
        icon: SettingOutlined,
        breadcrumb: false,
        submenu: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    key: 'pricing',
    path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/plan`,
    title: 'pricing',
    icon: DashboardOutlined,
    breadcrumb: false,
    premission:['ROLE_CLIENT'],
    submenu: [
      {
        key: 'pricing',
        path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/plan`,
        title: 'pricing',
        icon: DollarOutlined,
        breadcrumb: false,
        submenu: []
      },
      
    ]
  },
  {
    key: 'plan',
    path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/admin/plan`,
    title: 'Plan',
    icon: DollarOutlined,
    breadcrumb: false,
    premission:['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    submenu: [
      {
        key: 'add-plan',
        path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/admin/plan/add`,
        title: 'Add plan',
        icon: PlusOutlined ,
        breadcrumb: false,
        submenu: []
      },
      {
        key: 'plans',
        path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/admin/plan/list`,
        title: 'Plan list',
        icon: FileTextOutlined,
        breadcrumb: false,
        submenu: []
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    key: 'feature',
    path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/admin/feature`,
    title: 'feature',
    icon: DollarOutlined,
    breadcrumb: false,
    premission:['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    submenu: [
      {
        key: 'add-feature',
        path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/admin/feature/add`,
        title: 'Add feature',
        icon: PlusOutlined ,
        breadcrumb: false,
        submenu: []
      },
      {
        key: 'features',
        path: `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/admin/feature/list`,
        title: 'Feature list',
        icon: FileTextOutlined,
        breadcrumb: false,
        submenu: []
      },
    ]
  },
]

const navigationConfig = [
  ...NewSideBar
]



export default navigationConfig;

and this is the NavigationConfig component.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Menu, Dropdown, Button, Avatar, Modal, Form, Input, message, Upload, Tooltip } from "antd";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom/cjs/react-router-dom.min";
import { connect, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { ChangeOrganisation } from "redux/actions";
import { PlusOutlined, RollbackOutlined, BankOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import OrganisationService from "services/OrganisationService";
import { env } from "configs/EnvironmentConfig";

export const NavOrganisation = (props) => {
    const { ChangeOrganisation, name, icon, id, username } = props;

    const [ownedOrganisation, setOwnedOrganisation] = useState([]);
    const [joinedOrganisation, setJoinedOrganisation] = useState([]);
    const history = useHistory();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [showJoinModel, setShowJoinModel] = useState(false)


    useEffect(() => {
        OrganisationService.GetOwnedOrganisation().then((response) => {
            setOwnedOrganisation(response.data);
        });
        OrganisationService.GetJoinedOrganisations().then((response) => {
            setJoinedOrganisation(response.data);
        });
    }, [id]);

    const userTypeInOrganisation = (organisation) => {
        return organisation.members.find((member) => member.username === username).type;
    }

    const JoinModel = props => {
        const { visible, onCancel } = props
        const [form] = Form.useForm()
        const [join, setJoin] = useState(true)

        const handleSendRequest = () => {
            const { code } = form.getFieldsValue(['code']);
            OrganisationService.SendJoinRequest(code).then((resp) => {
                message.success(resp.data.message);
                onCancel();
                form.resetFields();
            });
        }

        const handleCreateOrganisation = () => {
            const { name, phone, adresse, icon } = form.getFieldsValue(['name', 'phone', 'adresse', 'icon']);
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('name', name);
            formData.append('phone', phone);
            formData.append('adresse', adresse);
            if (icon && icon.fileList.length > 0) {
                formData.append('icon', icon.fileList[0].originFileObj);
            }
            OrganisationService.CreateOrganisation(formData).then((resp) => {
                message.success('Organisation created successfully');
                onCancel();
                form.resetFields();
                dispatch(ChangeOrganisation({
                    id: resp.data.id,
                    name: resp.data.name,
                    isOwner: false,
                    userType: "owner",
                    "code": resp.data.code,
                    "icon": resp.data.icon
                }));
                history.push("/app/home");
            });
        }

        return (
            <Modal
                visible={visible}
                width={650}
                closable={false}
                title={join ? 'Join Organisation' : 'Create Organisation'}
                footer={[
                    <Button key="back" className="btn btn-light" onClick={onCancel}>
                        Cancel
                    </Button>,
                    <Button type={'primary'} onClick={() => {
                        form.validateFields(['code'])
                            .then((values) => {
                                if (Object.values(values).every(value => value)) {
                                    handleSendRequest();
                                    setJoin(true);
                                } else {
                                    setJoin(true);
                                }
                            })
                            .catch(() => {
                                message.error('Please put the code');
                                setJoin(true);
                            });
                    }} >
                        Join
                    </Button>,
                    <Button
                        type={'primary'}
                        ghost
                        onClick={() => {
                            form.validateFields(['name', 'phone', 'adresse'])
                                .then((values) => {
                                    if (Object.values(values).every(value => value)) {
                                        handleCreateOrganisation();
                                        setJoin(false);
                                    } else {
                                        setJoin(false);
                                    }
                                })
                                .catch(() => {
                                    message.error('Please fill all the fields');
                                    setJoin(false);
                                });
                        }}
                    >
                        Create
                    </Button>
                ]}
                centered
            >
                <Form form={form} labelCol={{ span: 8 }}>
                    {join ?
                        <Form.Item name={'code'} label={'Organisation Code'} rules={[
                            {
                                required: true,
                                message: 'Please input the organisation code'
                            }
                        ]}>
                            <Input />
                        </Form.Item>
                        :
                        <>
                            <Form.Item name={'name'} label={'Organisation Name'} rules={[
                                {
                                    required: true,
                                    message: 'Please input the organisation name'
                                }
                            ]}>
                                <Input />
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Form.Item name={'phone'} label={'Organisation phone'} rules={[
                                {
                                    required: true,
                                    message: 'Please input the organisation phone'
                                }
                            ]}>
                                <Input />
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Form.Item name={'adresse'} label={'Organisation addresse'} rules={[
                                {
                                    required: true,
                                    message: 'Please input the organisation address'
                                }
                            ]}>
                                <Input />
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Form.Item name={'icon'} label={'Organisation icon'}>
                                <Upload action="/upload.do" listType="picture-card">
                                    <button
                                        style={{
                                            border: 0,
                                            background: 'none',
                                        }}
                                        type="button"
                                    >
                                        <PlusOutlined />
                                        <div
                                            style={{
                                                marginTop: 8,
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            Upload
                                        </div>
                                    </button>
                                </Upload>
                            </Form.Item>
                        </>
                    }
                </Form>
            </Modal>
        )
    }

    const organisationMenu = (
        <div className="nav-profile nav-dropdown">
            <div className="nav-profile-header d-flex justify-content-between">
                <div className="ml-2" onClick={() => setShowJoinModel(true)} style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
                    <Avatar size={30}><PlusOutlined /></Avatar>
                    <span className="ml-2">Join Organisation</span>
                </div>
                <div className="ml-2" onClick={(e) => {
                    dispatch(ChangeOrganisation({
                        id: "",
                        name: "",
                        isOwner: false,
                        userType: "",
                        "code": "",
                    }))
                }}
                    style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
                >
                    <Tooltip title="Back to Profile">
                        <Avatar size={30} style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                            <RollbackOutlined style={{ color: 'black' }} />
                        </Avatar>

                    </Tooltip>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="nav-profile-body">
                <Menu>
                    {ownedOrganisation.map((organisation) => (
                        <Menu.Item
                            key={organisation.id}
                            onClick={(e) => {
                                dispatch(ChangeOrganisation({
                                    id: organisation.id,
                                    name: organisation.name,
                                    isOwner: true,
                                    userType: "owner",
                                    "code": organisation.code,
                                    "icon": organisation.icon,
                                    "phone": organisation.phone,
                                }));
                                history.push("/app/home");
                            }}
                            className="d-flex justify-content-between"
                        >
                            <div>
                                {organisation.icon ?
                                    <Avatar src={env.IMG_SRC + organisation.icon}></Avatar>
                                    :
                                    <Avatar>{organisation.name}</Avatar>
                                }
                                <span className="ml-2">{organisation.name}</span>
                            </div>
                            {/* <span>{organisation.code}</span> */}

                        </Menu.Item>
                    ))}
                    {joinedOrganisation.map((organisation) => (
                        <Menu.Item
                            key={organisation.id}
                            onClick={(e) => {
                                dispatch(ChangeOrganisation({
                                    id: organisation.id,
                                    name: organisation.name,
                                    isOwner: false,
                                    userType: userTypeInOrganisation(organisation),
                                    "code": organisation.code,
                                    "icon": organisation.icon,
                                    "phone": organisation.phone,
                                }));
                                history.push("/app/home");
                            }}
                            className="d-flex justify-content-between"
                        >
                            <div>
                                {organisation.icon ?
                                    <Avatar src={env.IMG_SRC + organisation.icon}></Avatar>
                                    :
                                    <Avatar>{organisation.name}</Avatar>
                                }
                                <span className="ml-2">{organisation.name}</span>
                            </div>
                            {/* <span>{organisation.code}</span> */}
                        </Menu.Item>
                    ))}
                </Menu>
            </div>

        </div>
    );

    return (
        <>
            {ownedOrganisation.length === 0 && joinedOrganisation.length === 0 ?
                <Button className="mt-3" onClick={() => setShowJoinModel(true)}>
                    <PlusOutlined />
                    <span>New</span>
                </Button>
                :
                <Dropdown
                    placement="bottomRight"
                    overlay={organisationMenu}
                    trigger={["click"]}
                >
                    <Menu className="d-flex align-item-center" mode="horizontal">
                        <Menu.Item>
                            <Tooltip title="Organisations">
                                {id ?
                                    icon ?
                                        <Avatar src={env.IMG_SRC + icon}></Avatar>
                                        :
                                        <Avatar>{name}</Avatar>
                                    :
                                    <Avatar size={50} className="mb-1 bg-white" icon={<BankOutlined style={{ color: 'black' }} />} />
                                }
                            </Tooltip>
                        </Menu.Item>
                    </Menu>
                </Dropdown>
            }
            <JoinModel
                visible={showJoinModel}
                onCancel={() => setShowJoinModel(false)}
            />
        </>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ org, auth }) => {
    const { id, name, type, isOwner, icon } = org;
    const { username } = auth;
    return { id, name, type, isOwner, icon, username };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { ChangeOrganisation })(NavOrganisation);

and this is the NavOrganisation component wher ei change the org state
the issue is when i wanna chage in the org state in the redux store i expect the menu content to change i mean hide or show items , but instead i get this error :Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

That's quite a sizable code-dump, where was the error triggered? Generally that error is pretty simple, you're likely calling a hook inside a conditional or after a return.

React hooks should be called on the component level, not inside the function that is defined inside the React component.
For example:
export const SideNavContent = (props) => {
  const IsAuth = (premission) => {
    const { isAuth: isAuthenticated } = useAuth([premission]);
    return isAuthenticated;
  };


  return <div>...</div>;
};

here useAuth is a hook that is being used inside the function that is not a component by itself. The right approach would be to move useAuth to the SideNavContent component.
If this is not solving your issue share me the complete stack trace.

it dosen't solve the issue

Share me the error stack trace that you see in the console.

    import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Menu, Grid } from "antd";
import IntlMessage from "../util-components/IntlMessage";
import Icon from "../util-components/Icon";
import navigationConfig from "configs/NavigationConfig";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { SIDE_NAV_LIGHT } from "constants/ThemeConstant";
import utils from "utils";
import { onMobileNavToggle } from "redux/actions/Theme";
import useAuth from "hooks/useAuth";
import useUserType from "hooks/useType";

const { SubMenu } = Menu;
const { useBreakpoint } = Grid;



const setLocale = (isLocaleOn, localeKey) =>
  isLocaleOn ? <IntlMessage id={localeKey} /> : localeKey.toString();

const setDefaultOpen = (key) => {
  let keyList = [];
  let keyString = "";
  if (key) {
    const arr = key.split("-");
    for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
      const elm = arr[index];
      index === 0 ? (keyString = elm) : (keyString = `${keyString}-${elm}`);
      keyList.push(keyString);
    }
  }
  return keyList;
};

const useConstructor = (callBack = () => { }) => {
  const [hasBeenCalled, setHasBeenCalled] = useState(false);
  const data = callBack();
  if (hasBeenCalled) return data;
  setHasBeenCalled(true);
  return data;
};

const MenuContent = (props) => {
  const {
    sideNavTheme,
    routeInfo,
    hideGroupTitle,
    localization,
    onMobileNavToggle,
  } = props;
  const data = useConstructor(() => {

    return navigationConfig;
  });

  const IsAuth = (premission) => {
    const { isAuth: isAuthenticated } = useAuth([premission]);
    return isAuthenticated;
  };

  const ExactAuth = (premission) => {
    const { exact } = useAuth([premission]);
    return exact;
  };

  const IsType = (requiredType) => {
    const { hasRequiredType } = useUserType([requiredType]);
    return hasRequiredType;
  };

  const isMobile = !utils.getBreakPoint(useBreakpoint()).includes("lg");
  const closeMobileNav = () => {
    if (isMobile) {
      onMobileNavToggle(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Menu
      theme={sideNavTheme === SIDE_NAV_LIGHT ? "light" : "dark"}
      mode="inline"
      style={{ height: "100%", borderRight: 0 }}
      defaultSelectedKeys={[routeInfo?.key]}
      defaultOpenKeys={setDefaultOpen(routeInfo?.key)}
      className={hideGroupTitle ? "hide-group-title" : ""}
    >
      {data.map((menu) =>
        menu.submenu.length > 0 ? (
          menu.exactAuth !== true ? (
            IsAuth(menu.premission) ? (
              (menu.userType === undefined || IsType(menu.userType)) ? (
                <Menu.ItemGroup
                  key={menu.key}
                  title={setLocale(localization, menu.title)}
                >
                  {menu.submenu.map((subMenuFirst) =>
                    subMenuFirst.submenu.length > 0 ? (
                      IsAuth(subMenuFirst.premission) ? (
                        <SubMenu
                          icon={
                            subMenuFirst.icon ? (
                              <Icon type={subMenuFirst?.icon} />
                            ) : null
                          }
                          key={subMenuFirst.key}
                          title={setLocale(localization, subMenuFirst.title)}
                        >
                          {subMenuFirst.submenu.map((subMenuSecond) =>
                            IsAuth(subMenuSecond.premission) ? (
                              <Menu.Item key={subMenuSecond.key}>
                                {subMenuSecond.icon ? (
                                  <Icon type={subMenuSecond?.icon} />
                                ) : null}
                                <span>
                                  {setLocale(localization, subMenuSecond.title)}
                                </span>
                                <Link
                                  onClick={() => closeMobileNav()}
                                  to={subMenuSecond.path}
                                />
                              </Menu.Item>
                            ) : null
                          )}
                        </SubMenu>
                      ) : null
                    ) : IsAuth(subMenuFirst.premission) ? (
                      <Menu.Item key={subMenuFirst.key}>
                        {subMenuFirst.icon ? (
                          <Icon type={subMenuFirst.icon} />
                        ) : null}
                        <span>{setLocale(localization, subMenuFirst.title)}</span>
                        <Link
                          onClick={() => closeMobileNav()}
                          to={subMenuFirst.path}
                        />
                      </Menu.Item>
                    ) : null
                  )}
                </Menu.ItemGroup>
              ) : null
            ) : null
          ) : ExactAuth(menu.premission) ? (
            <Menu.ItemGroup
              key={menu.key}
              title={setLocale(localization, menu.title)}
            >
              {menu.submenu.map((subMenuFirst) =>
                subMenuFirst.submenu.length > 0 ? (
                  IsAuth(subMenuFirst.premission) ? (
                    <SubMenu
                      icon={
                        subMenuFirst.icon ? (
                          <Icon type={subMenuFirst?.icon} />
                        ) : null
                      }
                      key={subMenuFirst.key}
                      title={setLocale(localization, subMenuFirst.title)}
                    >
                      {subMenuFirst.submenu.map((subMenuSecond) =>
                        IsAuth(subMenuSecond.premission) ? (
                          <Menu.Item key={subMenuSecond.key}>
                            {subMenuSecond.icon ? (
                              <Icon type={subMenuSecond?.icon} />
                            ) : null}
                            <span>
                              {setLocale(localization, subMenuSecond.title)}
                            </span>
                            <Link
                              onClick={() => closeMobileNav()}
                              to={subMenuSecond.path}
                            />
                          </Menu.Item>
                        ) : null
                      )}
                    </SubMenu>
                  ) : null
                ) : IsAuth(subMenuFirst.premission) ? (
                  <Menu.Item key={subMenuFirst.key}>
                    {subMenuFirst.icon ? (
                      <Icon type={subMenuFirst.icon} />
                    ) : null}
                    <span>{setLocale(localization, subMenuFirst.title)}</span>
                    <Link
                      onClick={() => closeMobileNav()}
                      to={subMenuFirst.path}
                    />
                  </Menu.Item>
                ) : null
              )}
            </Menu.ItemGroup>
          ) : null
        ) : IsAuth(menu.premission) ? (
          <Menu.Item key={menu.key}>
            {menu.icon ? <Icon type={menu?.icon} /> : null}
            <span>{setLocale(localization, menu?.title)}</span>
            {menu.path ? (
              <Link onClick={() => closeMobileNav()} to={menu.path} />
            ) : null}
          </Menu.Item>
        ) : null
      )}
    </Menu>
  );

};

const mapStateToProps = ({ theme }) => {
  const { sideNavTheme, topNavColor } = theme;
  return { sideNavTheme, topNavColor };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { onMobileNavToggle })(MenuContent);

i change the menuContent component to this , and still get the same error

You didn't solve your issue, so this is not an answer, rather an update to your question.
Please delete it and update your question.
